# Global version of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem

Tags: reference-request, differential-equations

Let $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an arbitrary (not necessarily closed) interval and $f:I\times \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ a continuous function such that in $I\times \mathbb{R}^{n}$ satisfies a global Lipschitz condition on its second variable. Then is it true that:

> For every point $(a,b)\in I\times \mathbb{R}^{n}$ there exists a a
>   solution to the equation $y^{\prime}=f(x,y)$ defined over the entire
>   $I$

Picard-Lindelöf theorem states that there exists a solution in a local closed neighborhood $[a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon]$. One could try to glue the local solutions to get a global one but then there will be a problem with the boundary of the resulting (possibly) open interval.

Does such a globally defined solution always exist? Are there references in the literature on this?

Comment: Yes, this implies global existence because you have an a priori lower bound on the maximal interval of existence that you can iterate. Any moderately advanced basic ODE textbook will discuss this.

Comment: Are you assuming that $I$ is compact? because I meant that $I$ is an arbitrary interval. Of course if $I$ is compact it will be a simple generalization of PL. I don't follow your meaning of "because you have an a priori lower bound on the maximal interval of existence that you can iterate. ".

Comment: I'm not using that $I$ is compact. Another easy argument is to use the fact that I have a comparison principle for first order ODEs, so $y$ can't grow faster than the solutions of $u'=Lu+g(x)$, and you can't have blow up in finite time.

Comment: Look up the (easy) proof that you have global existence for linear ODEs. The same argument will answer your question.

Comment: There is a global solution in the interior of $I$. For any $t$ in the interior of $I$ you just define $y(t)$ to be the value of the unique solution of your equation. If $I$ has a boundary, you can define $y(b)$ by a limit from the interior.

Comment: Thanks  Vít Tuček. But what I don't understand is exactly why such a limit exists. I think we should show that the solution $y$ is unifromly continuous on the interior of $I$. I don't see this yet. Maybe I should think more.

Comment: Of course I agree that $y(t)$ can't go to $\infty$ as I said earlier. But still $y$ can be bounded but yet $\lim_{t\to b} y(t)$ does not exist.

Comment: @DariusMath This cannot happen: since the function $y$ is a bounded solution of the differential equation, the function $x \mapsto y' (x) = f (x, y (x))$ is bounded in a neighbourhood of the point $b$, and thus the function $y$ is uniformly continuous, and hence has a limit at the point $b$.

Comment: @ Jean Van Schaftingen Thanks. Yes I have also come to this point and I convinced myself that the limit exists. Thanks for confirming this idea though

Answer (score 0):

You have existence on open intervals $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$, whose union covers entire closed interval $I$. Therefore you can choose a finite subcover, call it $I_n, 0<n<N$. You can also contract them so that only consecutively numbered ones would intersect, $I_n\cap I_m=\emptyset, |m-n|>1$. That would allow you to extend solution consecutively from one subinterval to the next.

Comment: But you are assuming that $I$ is closed. Of course if I is compact it will be a simple generalization of PL. I meant for an arbitrary -possibly open-interval.